# Lindelöf hypothesis claim

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory

I was randomly browsing, when I found [this puff piece](https://viterbischool.usc.edu/news/2018/06/mathematician-m-d-solves-one-of-the-greatest-open-problems-in-the-history-of-mathematics/) claiming a proof of the Lindelöf hypothesis by [Fokas.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanassios_S._Fokas) Note that the Wikipedia article says that he claimed, then withdrew his claim in 2017, but the USC piece is dated June 25 2018. So, what is the truth?

Comment: There is a revised Arxiv print of his dated June 19 2018.  The truth is that Wikipedia does not update as quickly, and I imagine some are waiting for expert review.  Gerhard "Puffs Wait For No One" Paseman, 2018.06.28.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman You could update Wikipedia yourself, that would take a few minutes :-), it's how Wikipedia works (I won't do that since I am not an expert of the domain and I know nothing about this problem).

Comment: As I read it, the June 19 version does not appear to claim that he has proved the Lindelöf hypothesis.  "Hence, since the above identity is valid for all $\epsilon$, this asymptotic identity suggests the validity of Lindelöf's hypothesis".

Comment: @RobertIsrael He certainly does claim it everywhere else, it seems :)

Comment: I agree with Robert Israel. The claims closest to the LH are (1.5)-(1.6) in the paper. In particular, if (1.6) is valid, then the LH is equivalent to the statement that that the real part of (1.7) is $O(t^\epsilon)$. It seems, however, that the proofs of (1.5)-(1.6) are not completed in this paper. See in particular the remarks on pp. 51-52: "in order to complete the rigorous derivation of (1.5) the following tasks are required" and "the completion of the rigorous justification of equation (1.6) requires the following". The last sentence suggests that these points will be addressed in [FKL].

Comment: I happened to attend this colloquium talk at UMass Amherst by Fokas in March 2018: http://www.math.umass.edu/calendar/distinguished-lecture/17401. During the talk he definitely claimed that the proof of the Lindelöf hypothesis was forthcoming (some parts joint with coauthors); apparent he had already achieved a "formal derivation" of LH in some sense but still needed more hard analytic work to rigorously verify this derivation. (I know nothing of this area so my memory/paraphrasing could be way off.)

Comment: @SamHopkins: That colloquium talk was on March 29, that is, between versions 3 and 4 of his arXiv preprint (https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.06607). In version 3 he says "using the fact that [...] the lhs of (1.16) satisfies the Lindelöf hypothesis, it is possible to show that the Riemann zeta function satisfies the same hypothesis. [...] rigorous details are provided in [FKL]." In version 4 he says that "(1.6) suggests the validity of Lindelöf's hypothesis", and he no longer claims that the proof of the LH is forthcoming.

Comment: I also fail to see what are the (deep!) consequences for quantum computing (as claimed in the puff) :-)

Answer (score 6):

(Not an answer of any sort, just too long for a comment.)  The main result 
seems to be an integral equation (1.3) of the form 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(t,\tau) |\zeta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it\tau)|^2\,d\tau={\mathcal G}(t)$$
with  some explicit functions $K$ and ${\mathcal G}$.  This equation (if true) is presumably 
new, and may be interesting.

However, in my view, how interesting it is would   depend  quite a bit on whether $|\zeta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it\tau)|^2$ is the  only  solution of it.  This sort of integral operators  may have kernels, and  if it is the  case then it would be rather  difficult to squeeze   the Lindelöf hypothesis  out of it.  (If I were the author then this is where I would look.)

P.S. For those who have  read ``puff piece'':  As pointed out by  Robert Israel, indeed,
in the (this far, latest) version 4 a proof of the Lindelöf hypothesis   is not claimed.

P.P.S Take the above with a pinch of salt; the last time I was involved with this subject was decades ago.

Comment: [Some](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/05/04/polymath15-ninth-thread-going-below-0-22/#comment-501896) are not too hopeful with respect to this approach...

Answer (score 5):

I'm putting this as an answer because I haven't got enough reputation to post a comment.

In [a paper published on 25 September 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09440), written jointly with A Ashton, A Fokas asserts that a relation derived in that paper "provides the starting point of a novel approach which *in a series of companion papers yields a formal proof of the Lindelöf hypothesis*" (my emphasis).

Answer (score 0):

From the announcement of the *Séminaire Bourbaki du vendredi* on 28/1/2022 :

[image: Farrel Brumley says that the Lindelöf Hypothesis is out of bounds at present]

Comment: This is a survey of new work (presumably mostly about Paul Nelson's preprint from Sep 2021) which has nothing to do with Fokas. It also has nothing to do with Lindelof, in some sense, because it is about extending to more general L-functions things that have been known for $\zeta$ for decades ("resolu par Weyl et Hardy-Littlewood"). So it is clearly not relevant to this (long-dormant) thread.

Comment: PS: Chandan, have you perhaps been misled by the Quanta Magazine article on Nelson's work? It is staggeringly misleading, even by Quanta's dubious standards.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I wanted to merely point out that Brumley asserts that the Lindelöf Hypothesis is out of reach at present, and therefore indirectly says that it has not been proved by Fokas.